# How do I programmatically pull up a different storyboard when a button is clicked in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code so far

```
joinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
}
 @objc func buttonAction(_sender: UIButton) {
    print("I want to go to a storyboard here")
 }
```

I have everything coded (never used storyboard), but now I want to actually manually play with the UI now. How can I manually play with the storyboard? Or even render out to a different viewcontroller? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programatically this way:

**Swift 3+**

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
   let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as UIViewController
   present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! Was stuck on this. This code makes sense too :) !

Comment: **Welcome** @zyne

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a `Storyboard ID` to the view controllers you are going to use programatically:

1. Select storyboard
2. Go to `Identity Inspector` (`⌥⌘3`)
3. Assign `Storyboard ID`

If you want to add manual segue in Storyboard (Note: you can have multiple manual segues):

1. Select storyboard
2. Select the source view controller
3. Go to `Connections Inspector` (`⌥⌘6`)
4. In the `Triggered Segues`, drag the dot beside `manual` to the target view controller and select the desired method
5. In `Document Outline`, select "Show segue..." and go to `Attributes Inspector` (`⌥⌘4`) and assign an `Identifier`

In your button function, you can simply use the segue by:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "<IdentifierForSegue>", sender: self)
```

Or if you do not wish to use a manual segue:

```
// If view controllers are in the same Storyboard
let storyboard = self.storyboard!
// If view controllers are in different Storyboards
// let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "<NameOfYourStoryboard>", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "<IdentifierForTargetViewController>")
// If you don't have a navigation controller
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
// If you have a navigation controller
// self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to drag to my view controller. Keep in mind this is my only storyboard and that everything else was coded in.
Do I make the segue going to itself or something? I don't get it :(

Comment: Say you have two view controllers A and B, if you want to go from A to B, then the select the storyboard and select the view controller A and to go `Connections Inspector`, you should see the `Triggered Segues` at top, there should be a dot beside `manual`, drag it to view controller B.

Comment: I only have one view controller since I created a collectionviewcontroller programmatically, so I can't even connect A to B.

Comment: The just follow the last step and either call `present` or `pushViewController` with the collectionviewcontroller you created